# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error

Tags: java, arrays

My array has an unfixed size as it depends on the user input for the number of modules entered so I really don't know what to do when I run this code and got this error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

```
    Module[] array = new Module[moduleno];
    String[] a = new String[moduleno];
    String[] b = new String[moduleno];
    int[] c = new int[moduleno];
    String[] Output = new String[moduleno];
    String endoutput="";

  //Method for input of number of modules
     moduleno = Student.modno();

     for (int i = 0; i < moduleno; i++) {

            modulename = Student.MakingModName(i);
            grade = Student.readGrade(i);
            cu = Student.readCredits(i);
            value = Student.GradeValue(grade);
            score = Student.calculateScore(value, cu);
            totalScore += score;
            totalCu += cu;
            GPA = Student.calculateGPA(totalCu, totalScore);

             //Error occurs here.
            **array[i] = new Module(modulename,grade,cu);**
            a[i] = array[i].getModulename();

            b[i] = array[i].getGrade();
            c[i] = array[i].getCu();


            Output[i] = a[i] + "                " +b[i]+"             " +c[i]+"              ";
            endoutput = endoutput + Output[i] + "\n";
        }
```

Comment: in which line do you get error

Comment: Where are the arrays initialised and which one is causing the error?

Comment: what is an "unfixed array size"? It seems you have created array with zero length.

Comment: @Henry  how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This sequence of statements:

```
Module[] array = new Module[moduleno];
moduleno = Student.modno();
```

does not magically resize the array that has been allocated previously. You need to do it the other way round:

```
moduleno = Student.modno();
Module[] array = new Module[moduleno];
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the statement

```
moduleno = Student.modno(); // this should be the value while you initialize the array
```

before you initialize your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add This line before initialize your array
**moduleno = Student.modno();**

Module[] array = new Module[moduleno];
String[] a = new String[moduleno];
String[] b = new String[moduleno];
int[] c = new int[moduleno];
String[] Output = new String[moduleno];
String endoutput="";
```

**Reason :**
By default your **moduleno**  variable contains 0(Zero) size so your all arrays size is also 0(Zero).

And you try to add 1 element in array but size of array is zero so it gives ArrayIndexOutBoundsException.